# override function in C++

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I'm trying to stop class B from accessing DoSomething(Class Y) function and only access DoSomething(Class X) . How can I do that in C++ ?.

```
Class A {
    public:
        void DoSomething(Class Y);
}

Class B: public A { 
    public:
        void DoSomething(Class X);   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop class B"?  Can you give an example of some code that is doing the wrong thing?

Comment: Make `DoSomething(Class Y)` in `A` `private` or define it in `B` as `{ }`? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MujtabaAlboori: But then what?  Please give a concrete example of some code that is calling the wrong function (edit your question to include this code).

Comment: If I want use class like this B imB; imB.DoSomething(X); only, so imB.A:DoSomething(Y) should not be accessible.

Comment: inherit class A privately would be one way, but that might cut off options you need. actual code would be helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `A::DoSomething(Class Y)` `private`, and that's about the only way you can go about it.

Also, you're not overriding here, but hiding. Still, in `class` (yes, it's lower-case, not upper-case) B, you can still call `A::DoSomething()`. `private`'s the only way to deny access.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to stop class B from accessing `DoSomething(Class Y)`. How can I do that in C++ ?

Like this:

```
class X {};
class Y {};

class A {
    public:
        void DoSomething(class Y);
};

class B: public A {
    public:
        void DoSomething(class X);
};

int main () {
  B b;
  Y y;
  b.DoSomething(y);

  // Note that b can still access DoSomething(y) if you want it to:
  b.A::DoSomething(y);
}
```

Notice the error message that this produces in g++:

```
g++ -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror    b.cc   -o b
b.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
b.cc:17:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::DoSomething(Y&)’
b.cc:17:18: note: candidate is:
b.cc:11:14: note: void B::DoSomething(X)
b.cc:11:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Y’ to ‘X’
```

Comment: You can still access `A::DoSomething` from class B... something your code doesn't show.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, you and I took his question to mean different things. Your comment is correct. I'll update my answer to reflect it.